# Spanning trees in a graph

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be a graph with no loops or cut edges. Show that $t(G)\geq e(G)$. Here, $t(G)$ is the number of spanning trees in $G$.

Here it says that the graph has no loops or cut edges this implies that the graph has no cut vertices and therefore there exist greater than or equal to $2$ many edge disjoint paths between any two vertices. The number of edges in each spanning tree is $n-1$ where $n$ is the number of vertices. I know the equality holds when the graph is $C_n$. Please help me with this. Thank you

Comment: If you mean $t(G)$ to count the number of trees that span $G$, you should say so in the body of the Question.

Answer (score 1):

Hint.

If $e$ is an arbitrary edge of graph $G$, then by condition graph $G-e$ is connected. Hence it has a spanning tree $T_e$. The same tree is a spanning tree for graph $G$. If $e'$ and $e''$ are different edges of graph $G$, then the trees $T_{e'}$ and $T_{e''}$ are different.